# Unset multidimensional array item based on value not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to unset array item in my multidimensional array. However the approach is working for only first loop (which is not my case) in second loop `unset` doesn't work.

I have tried to find here but unable to get the result with those resolution. So eventually posting with new thread.

```
$arr = [
    'subnav'  => [
        'first'  => [
            'one'   => 'hello',
            'two'   => 'Jatin',
            'admin' => TRUE,
        ],
        'second' => [
            'one'   => 'hello',
            'two'   => 'Priya',
            'admin' => FALSE,
        ],
    ],
    'pagenav' => [
        'cook'   => [
            'one'   => 'hello',
            'two'   => 'Rahul',
            'admin' => TRUE,
        ],
        'driver' => [
            'one'   => 'hello',
            'two'   => 'Vijay',
            'admin' => TRUE,
        ],
    ],
];

foreach ( $arr as $floop => $fval ) {

    foreach ( $fval as $nav => $item ) {
        if ( $item[ 'admin' ] == FALSE ) {
            unset( $fval[ $nav ] );
        }
    }
}
```

So here I want to remove every item which has `admin => false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try unset a variable not the array so try that

```
foreach ( $arr as $floop => $fval ) {

   foreach ( $fval as $nav => $item ) {
      if ( $item[ 'admin' ] == FALSE ) {
        unset( $arr[$floop][ $nav ] );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: (Not tested)

```
function unsetAdmin(&$array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            unsetAdmin($value);
        }
        if (false === $value && $key == 'admin') {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```